# How can I do a lookup in mongoDB with two foreign keys?

Tags: mongodb, lookup

Three collections Product, ProductDescription, Language like this:

```
> db.Language.find();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234..."),
    "isoCc" : "EN"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5678..."),
    "isoCc" : "DE"
}

> db.Product.find();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3eff..."),
    "sku" : "123456",
    "title" : "Some Product Title"
}

> db.ProductDescription.find();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("44ad..."),
    "ofProduct" : ObjectId("3eff..."),
    "ofLanguage" : ObjectId("1234..."),
    "shortDescription" : "English description"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("f5aa..."),
    "ofProduct" : ObjectId("3eff..."),
    "ofLanguage" : ObjectId("5678..."),
    "shortDescription" : "German description"
}
```

If I do a lookup on the ProductDescription like this

```
db.Product.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "ProductDescription",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "ofProduct",
        as: "description"
      }
  }
])
```

I get both entrys of ProductDescription.

So how can I also filter what language the description should be?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lookup description language also then you need to use another lookup for `description.ofLanguage`

```
db.Product.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "ProductDescription",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "ofProduct",
        as: "description"
      }
  },
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "Language",
        localField: "description.ofLanguage",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "language"
      }
  }
])
```